# What exactly does Apple require for a reachability test?

Tags: ios, reachability

Does Apple require ongoing reachability testing (and alerting), or can one just test once at App launch?  This is all Apple says: "it's very important that your code include a customer alert or notification when the network is not available." Quote from: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html.  This doesn't make it clear whether the App must continuously monitor the connection status, or whether just checking at App launch is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't have to continuously monitor the network connection. And if your app can still do something sensible if there is no network connection, there is no *requirement* to notify the user.

For example, I have an app that shows local train timetables. Whenever it starts, it checks for an updated timetable from my web site (the timetable is updated every few weeks). If there is no network, then no problem, the app continues and *does not* notify the user. If there is network connectivity but no new timetable, no problem. If there is a new timetable, it is downloaded in the background and silently updated.

If your app requires network connectivity to do anything useful, then you will probably want to let the user know the reason why the app isn't working.

Comment: This isn't actually strictly true.  I have an app that can function, albeit in a limited mode, without connectivity, and I did not think it was necessary to notify the user when entering that mode.  Apple's reviewer did not accept that.  Obviously, Apple isn't always consistent enforcing policies, but my experience suggests that your statement ("no requirement to notify the user") is not really correct.